# "Hidden" keyboard layout in Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

Having more than three layouts... is difficult and sometimes infuriating. I would like to know if it is possible to "hide" the layout so that you don’t have to switch to it using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but let's say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Making your own layout is not an option, because it’s better to get used to 4 layouts than to struggle with combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Language bar settings and their shortcuts can be set in this menu.

Windows Settings > Devices > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings > Language bar options

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I want... It's near, but I want to exclude several layouts from switching.
There I can't do this

Comment: @TheVorkMan I recommend turning off the hotkey for switching altogether and bind custom shortcuts to the layouts you want to use (Left Alt + Shift + 1; Left Alt + Shift + 2; ...)

Comment: Maybe, I will do like this, but I have one idea with scripts.
If it fails, I will accept this answer

Comment: Interesting, If I set combination to something other than Russian or English, it's will won't work. However, Russian and English working fine. It's not a fault from keyboard or something like that... (Russian working because I assume it was from setup)